# R play/run button missing

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

I recently started using R. I have been using the R Notebooks with Code Chunks and recently in a new notebook every new code chunk I create does not have the run button at the top right nor does it run when I select Run all from the top right run dropdown.

Picture of issue below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In RStudio,

*Tools > Global Options > R Markdown > Advanced > Show inline toolbar for R code Chunks*

That should make the buttons reappear.